# How do I diagnose bus error in fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm learning how to use fortran to do some data analysis. I'm working through the following example:

```
program linalg
  implicit none

  real :: v1(3), v2(3), m(3,3)
  integer :: i,j

  v1(1) = 0.25
  v1(2) = 1.2
  v1(3) = 0.2

  ! use nested do loops to initialise the matrix
  ! to the unit matrix
  do i=1,3
     do j=1,3
        m(i,j) = 0.0
     end do
     m(i,j) = 1.0
  end do

  ! do a matrix multiplicationof a vector equivalent to v2i = mij v1j
  do i = 1,3
     v2(i) = 0.0
     do j = 1,3
        v2(i) = v2(i) + m(i,j)*v1(j)
     end do
  end do

  write(*,*) 'v2 = ', v2

end program linalg
```

which I execute with

```
f95 -o linalg linalg.f90
./linalg
```

However, I get the following message in the terminal:

```
Bus error
```

Some links that I've followed online suggest that this is to do with not having pre-define a variable, but I am sure that I have in this script and cannot find where the error is coming from. Is there another reason I would be getting this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake is in here

```
  do i=1,3
     do j=1,3
        m(i,j) = 0.0
     end do
     m(i,j) = 1.0    ! here be a dragon
  end do
```

Fortran is explicit in stating that after the end of a loop the value of the index variable is 1 greater than the value it had on the last iteration of the loop.  So in this case the statement `m(i,j) = 1.0` will try to address `m(1,4)` at the first go round, then `m(2,4)`, and so forth.

Sometimes you get 'lucky' with an attempt to write outside the bounds of an array and the write stays inside the address space of the process you are working in.  'Lucky' in the sense that your program is wrong but doesn't crash -- this crash is a much better situation to be in.  The `bus error` suggests that the compiler has generated an address to write to that lies in forbidden territory for any process.

You could have found this yourself by turning on 'run-time bounds checking' with your compiler.  Your compiler's documentation, or other Qs and As here on SO, will tell you how to do that.

I'll leave it to you to fix this as you wish, you show every sign of being able to figure it out now you know the rules.